# Extract phrase that repeats in a string in R

Tags: regex, r, string, pattern-matching

The task is to extract phrase from a string using `R` software.

Consider having a set of strings, which have similar structure: string begins with a bracket `(` and closes with an other bracket `)`, and in between it has several identical phrases separated with comma `,`, e.g. `"(matrix,matrix,matrix)"`. It is not known in advance how many times the phrase repeats, so it can be 2 `"(matrix,matrix)"`,3, 4 `"(matrix,matrix,matrix,matrix,)"`, etc. repetitions. Usually up to 6.  If there is only one phrase, it is not in (additional) brackets (e.g.,`"matrix"` or `"(matrix)"`).

I managed to extract one phrase by using:

```
NAME <- "(matrix,matrix,matrix,matrix)"
gsub("(\\()(.*,){1,}(.*)\\)", "\\3",NAME, perl = T)
```

But there is a **more advanced question**: how can I *check*, if the phrase repeats, and *extract* it only if it repeats, otherwise leave it as-is? E.g. how to extract
`"matrix"` from `"(matrix,matrix,matrix,matrix)"`,
 `"A B"` from `"(A B,A B)"`,
`"(A,B,C)"` from `"((A,B,C),(A,B,C),(A,B,C),(A,B,C))"`, and
 `"A,B,C"` from `"(A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C)"`,
**but** `"(A,B,C)"` must be left intact, as it does not repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\((.+?)(?:,\1)+\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS3iP1/2)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\(` - opening round bracket
- `(.+?)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more characters other than a newline
- `(?:,\1)+` - 1 or more sequences of `,` followed with the value captured into Grouip 1
- `\)` - a closing round bracket.

R demo:

```
> s = "(matrix,matrix,matrix)"
> gsub("\\((.+?)(?:,\\1)+\\)", "\\1", s)
[1] "matrix"
> s = "(m,d,s)"
> gsub("\\((.+?)(?:,\\1)+\\)", "\\1", s)
[1] "(m,d,s)"
```

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor, especially for explanation :)